# Perl using the -i option on a vboxsf share: Can't remove input_file Text file busy, skipping file

Tags: perl, sed, virtualbox

System: Arch Linux in VirtualBox 5.1.26 on Windows 10 Host

I try to use perl like sed in the terminal for in place substitution the input file:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/orig/replace/g' input_file
```

But I always get:

```
Can't remove input_file Text file busy, skipping file
```

This happens only if the file is inside a VirtualBox vboxsf share. With all other tools (sed, mv, vim or whatever) it is no problem to change the file.

This problem seems to be related to:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2553
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4437

I can't find any solution googling around :(

**Update:**

Using `perl -i.bak -p -e 's/orig/replace/g' input_file` I get a similar message:

```
Can't rename input_file to input_file.bak: Text file busy, skipping file.
```

This is exactly the same message as gedit shows:

[image]

So it is the same behavior, but googling around I can only find the Gedit topic. It seems noone has noticed this with perl -i.

Comment: This is not a Perl problem.

Comment: The `-i` option without a value doesn't work on Windows file systems. The process is blocking itself from deleting the original input file. Try it with `-i.bak` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

While you are running a unix OS, you are still using a Windows file system. NTFS doesn't support anonymous files like unix file systems, and Perl `-i` requires support for anonymous files.

The workaround is to use a temporary files by using `-i<ext>` (e.g. `-i~`) instead of `-i`.

Comment: Sorry, does not work either: `$ perl -i.bak -p -e 's/orig/replace/g' input_file 
Can't rename input_file to input_file.bak: Text file busy, skipping file.`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. My solution is a bashscript. Copy files to tmp. Search and Replace. Overwrite tmp-files with original-files. Than delete tmp-dir. If you need you can use parameter in script for dynamic search&replace and create an alias for call the script direct and everywhere.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Removing text from .log files..."

echo "Creating tmp-dir..."
mkdir /tmp/myTmpFiles/

echo "Copy .log files to tmp..."
cp -v /home/user/sharedfolder/*.log /tmp/myTmpFiles/

echo "Search and Replace in tmp-files..."
perl -i -p0e 's/orig/replace/g' /tmp/myTmpFiles/*.log

echo "Copy .log to sharedfolder"
cp -v /tmp/myTmpFiles/*.log /home/user/sharedfolder/

echo "Remove tmp-dir..."
rm -vr /tmp/myTmpFiles/

echo "Done..."
```